# Azure VM Webhosting - IIS public access

Tags: azure, iis, sql-server-2012, azure-virtual-machine

I am hosting a website on my Azure classic VM, 2012 Server R2.  The application is MVC5 installed in wwwroot directory, runs on local host. The site binding type is Http, Port 80, and IP address is all unassigned.

To setup the public access I did the following:

1. Added endpoint TCP 80 private and public (Azure Portal)
2. Added inbound rule (firewall) Http port 80, the World Wide Web Services (HTTPS Traffic-In) was already open.

When I try to access the site http://xxxx.cloudapp.net, I get this error: can't reach this page!

Have I missed any step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete the VM and install a new one; however this time I did setup the endpoints before installing the VM, all works now.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the site name is configured wrongly in IIS? Is it the default website?

Comment: Yes it is the default website.